# Return Row to Array

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm work with C# and linq, and am trying to return some results from a table in a string, or array.
I am able to create a query, look up the row, but when I try to return column values, I get empty array of my table column names as my string.

Here is my result:

```
SELECT [t0].[UserID], [t0].[First], [t0].[Last], [t0].[Username], [t0].[Password], [t0].[Employee], [t0].[City], [t0].[Branch], [t0].[UserPoints], [t0].[CurrentPoints], [t0].[LastOnline], [t0].[Status] FROM [dbo].[mrobUsers] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Username] = @p0
```

Here is my Linq query:

```
 public string GetUserInfo(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
                {
                    var getInfo = (from row
                        in db.mrobUsers
                                     where row.Username == username 
                                   select row).ToString();
                    return getInfo;
                   // I've debugged up to here, and my user name is passed into this
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return MySerializer.Serialize(false);
            }
        }
```

My ideal result would be:

```
1,Mark,Rob,mrob88, password....etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
// You should change the return type of your method, if you want to return an array of
// strings.
public string[] GetUserInfo(string username)
{
    try
    {
        using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
        {
            // Get the user's info. 
            var userInfo = (from row in db.mrobUsers
                            where row.Username == username 
                            select row).SingleOrDefault();

            // If the user's info found return the corresponding values.
            if(userInfo!=null)
            {
                var t = typeof(userInfo);
                List<string> values = new List<string>();

                foreach(var prop in t.GetProperties())
                {
                    values.Add(prop.GetValue(userInfo, null);
                }

                return values.ToArray();
            }
            else // the user's info not found and return an empty array. 
            {
                return new string[] { };
            }
               // I've debugged up to here, and my user name is passed into this
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return MySerializer.Serialize(false);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I suggest you not follow this approach. I think it would be better, if you declare a class with properties the values that you want to retrieve, like below:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    // the same way you will declare the rest of your properties.
}
```

Then you could change your method to the following one:

```
public UserInfo GetUserInfo(string username)
{
    try
    {
        using (UserDataDataContext db = new UserDataDataContext())
        {
            // Get the user's info. 
            var userInfo = (from row in db.mrobUsers
                            where row.Username == username 
                            select new UserInfo
                            {
                                UserId = row.UserId,
                                First = row.First
                                Last = row.Last
                            }).SingleOrDefault();

            return userInfo;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return MySerializer.Serialize(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this `userInfo.Select(x=>x.ToString())` work on members? It will serialize the single element in the userInfo collection. I think OP wants each member to be an element of the resulting array.

Comment: I think you're better off just creating a collection and adding member values manually and finally call `ToArray` on it.

Comment: It's still incorrect. `userInfo.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray()` returns an array with 1 element, containing what the default `ToString` implementation returns.

Comment: @MarcelN. you are both correct. Please give me a few minutes to fix it. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @Christos: No problem, I was just pointing it out :). I have no actual use for it.

Comment: @Mark I will correct my first approach. However, I think that the second approach is more elegant.